# Tasker - Count The Amount Of Days Since A Certain Day

Tags: tasker

the title says is all
I want to create a task that holds a count from a certain date
My goal is then to use minimal text to display the amount of days, that part I know how to do it's just getting Tasker to do the sums
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first have to convert both dates to seconds using Variable Convert.  Then subtract those two values to get the number of seconds between the two dates and convert that value to the number of days by /24/60/60 (hours/minutes/seconds).

Here is a sample task that illustrates using 08-01-2014 as %startdate and today (%DATE) which is 08-23-2014 as %today.  The result is 22 days.

A1: Variable Set [ Name:%startdate To:08-01-2014 Do Maths:Off Append:Off ]

A2: Variable Convert [ Name:%startdate Function:Date Time to Seconds Store Result In:%startdateinseconds ]

A3: Variable Set [ Name:%today To:%DATE Do Maths:Off Append:Off ]

A4: Variable Convert [ Name:%today Function:Date Time to Seconds Store Result In:%todayinseconds ]

A5: Variable Set [ Name:%secondssince To:%todayinseconds - %startdateinseconds Do Maths:On Append:Off ]

A6: Variable Set [ Name:%dayssince To:%secondssince / 24 / 60 / 60  Do Maths:On Append:Off ]

You could shorten this a bit by eliminating A3 and replacing %today with %DATE in A4.  Also, you could combine A5 and A6 by using (%todayinseconds - %startdateinseconds) / 24 / 60 / 60.  I split it up only to show the individual steps better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ended up just figuring out the days and then adding 1 to it each day, but I will try this out for future reference!

Comment: No problem. I hope it helps you.